# Not able to deploy mule 4 application in on-premise using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, maven-plugin, mule4

[image]I'm trying to deploy mule 4 application using jenkin pipeline but in the deployement process getting the below mentioned error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project helloworld: Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:deploy failed: Mule Runtime is not running!

Adding my pom.xml.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
      <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule-application</packaging>
<name>helloworld</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <app.runtime>4.2.2</app.runtime>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.3.5</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    <proejct.site.deploy.url>E:\IDFC\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2\apps</proejct.site.deploy.url>

</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
             <standaloneDeployment>
                <muleHome>E:\IDFC\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2</muleHome>
                <muleVersion>4.2.2</muleVersion>
             </standaloneDeployment>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
             <id>default-deploy</id>
             <phase>deploy</phase>
             <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
             </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>  
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>anypoint-exchange-v2</id>
        <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

in Jenkins till build it's working but while deploying i'm getting error.
For the deploy process Using custom workspace Directory and executing the custom batch command mvn package deploy -DmuleDeploy.
Here it's failing with the below added error.
This is my standalone server where i have to deploy: C:\AnypointStudio\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2\apps

Can you please check my pom.xml anything else do i need to add there?
let me know where I am doing wrong to deploy on standalone server?

Answer (score -1):

The Mule Maven Plugin is complaining that the target standalone Mule Runtime at C:\AnypointStudio\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2\ is not running. The log error says as much: `Mule Runtime is not running!`. The [documentation for the standalone deployment configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/deploy-on-premises#standalone-deployment-parameters-reference) seems to imply that it should be executing.

You'll need to ensure it is up and running before trying to deploy to it.

Note, installing a standalone Mule Runtime inside a directory called AnypointStudio is a bit confusing. The standalone runtime is not part of Anypoint Studio nor it interacts with Studio in any way.

Comment: Hi @aled 
changed the standalone Mule Runtime to E:\IDFC\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2
and started mule.bat file. but still getting the same error while running mvn clean package deploy -DmuleDeploy in the project folder. Can you pls check anything else is required on pom.xml ?